# Replica trick in a two-dimensional gravitational model for a no time-reflecting geometry

Tags: gravity, entropy, quantum-gravity

I try to apply the replica trick in a two-dimensional gravitational model. I interesting for the case where the semiclassical geometry is an evaporating black hole. These geometries have no time-reflection symmetry. In many related articles they say that the geometries must have time-reflection symmetry, but I can't find why. It seems to me that the method can generalize to geometries with no time-reflection symmetry.